# Add data to a value prompt using javascript in Cognos 11

Tags: javascript, websphere, cognos, cognos-11, report-studio

I would like to know if we can add data in a value prompts using java script? The data doesn't come from any query subject, but hard-coded in java script?
For example, I have a value prompt named 'country'. And if I want a display value: 'US' and use value: 1; how would I achieve it in JS?

Thank you!
Hardik

Comment: Before you ask people to do your homework for you, like you did in the same question on Cognoise.com, you should know that's frowned upon here.  You should contact the Cognos report developer at your company.

Comment: I actually did my homework and it's ongoing too.. And thank you for the same response here, I appreciate that. But I am very new to JS and that documentation isn't helping me much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Here is a link to the Cognos report scripting documentation.

https://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/data/sw-library/cognos/mobile/scriptable_reports/ValuePromptControl.html